# dropdown value changes after refresh in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, local-storage

I am using local storage for a activity log of my employees. They choose their activity from a drop down box and the activity they choose stays in the drop down box after refresh in Firefox but goes back to default in Google Chrome. Is there a setting in Chrome that I need to change in order for it to retain the selected activity? Here is my code for one employee.

```
 <script>
 function foo1(a) {
 //alert(a.value);
 var d = new Date();
 var c = document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML;
 c = c + a.value + " was selected at: " + d.toString();
 document.getElementById("time1").innerHTML = c + '<br/>';
 localStorage.setItem(a.value, d.toString());
 }

 function load1() {
 var c = "Wholesale Pictures.: " + localStorage.getItem("Wholesale Pictures.") +   

 '<br/>';
 c += "NS Pictures.:" + localStorage.getItem("NS Pictures.") + '<br/>';
 c += "NS ERO's.:" + localStorage.getItem("NS ERO's.") + '<br/>';
 c += "BL ERO's.:" + localStorage.getItem("BL ERO's.") + '<br/>';
 c += "Wholesale Staging.:" + localStorage.getItem("Wholesale Staging.") + '<br/>';
 c += "Wholesale Scan.:" + localStorage.getItem("Wholesale Scan.") + '<br/>';
 c += "Sirius Tags.:" + localStorage.getItem("Sirius Tags.") + '<br/>';
 c += "Lunch Break.:" + localStorage.getItem("Lunch Break.") + '<br/>';
 document.getElementById("log1").innerHTML = c;
 }
 </script>

 <div class="david">
 <h2><img src="Images/david.jpg" class="img-circle">&nbsp&nbspDavid</h2>
 <p id="log1"></p>

 <select id="options" class="form-control" onchange="foo1(this)">
 <option>Select Work Area</option>
 <option>NS Pictures.</option>
 <option>NS ERO's.</option>
 <option>BL ERO's.</option>
 <option>Wholesale Staging.</option>
 <option>Wholesale Scan.</option>
 <option>Wholesale Pictures.</option>
 <option>Sirius Tags.</option>
 <option>Lunch Break.</option>
 </select>

 <div class="buttons">
 <button id="log1" onclick="load1()">Activity Log</button>
 </div>
 <p id="time1"><br/></p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not related to local storage, but rather a difference in how chrome and firefox handle form values when you soft-refresh a page. Firefox is nice enough to remember the last value of the form, and chrome isnt. You have nothing in your code that is trying to set the dropdown to the last selected value when the page loads. You would have to add something to your code to do that. You could store the last selected value to local storage, and then retrieve it on page load, like this:

```
foo1(a) {
//your code...
localStorage.setItem('lastViewed',a.value);
}
```

and then at the bottom of your page

```
<script>
var value=localStorage.getItem('lastViewed');
if (typeof value === "string")
{
    document.getElementById('options').value=value;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please accept the answer and/or upvote it if your issue has been addressed.